# SQLite weird duplicate database

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I'm working with SQLite in php, and I was just attempting to add a new column to table, and I went into my table.db file to check if it added it, and I noticed that I have 2 Users tables.

This is really weird to me, because I'm not sure how I have 2 tables with the same name? It also appears to save all of the data twice (Once to either table), which I believe is why I have been having some stability issues.

in my db file I have `„CtableUsersUsersCREATE TABLE Users(` **and** `„%tableUsersUsersCREATE TABLE Users(`

So my question is: Is this normal behavior? I'm fairly new to SQLite. And if not, how can I safely remove the 2nd table without deleting the 1st table at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some old data might still be in unused parts of some pages. This is harmless.

If it bothers you, run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).